# Generating ButtonPress Event with xlib

Tags: window, xlib, xorg, window-managers

I'm trying to write my own window manager in working with Xlib/X11. I have some trouble. To achieve some goals I decided to grab mouse pointer and filter mouse events.

I have used XGrabPointer to redirect all mouse messages to my application, but there's trouble - I can't obtain XID to the window, which should retrieve the message. Additionally, I don't be sure, that I correct fill xevent structure.

Comment: XGrabPointer, XID -- what are these technologies? You should specify in your message and via the tags which technology these types come from.

Comment: I tries add tag, like xlib or X Window System, but I'm unauthorized to add new tags.